# Imgix root subdomain redirect

Tags: cdn, imgix, imgix-js

Is it possible to place a redirect so users can not access/view my configuration details when they navigate to my example.imgix.net domain?

I tried seraching for this configuration in imgix's settings and reviewed their KB articles.